# jQuery check value of input field and use if 1 or greater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a very simple jQuery function which includes checking for a value of an input field and if that is greater than 0, setting a variable `counter` as that value. Otherwise use `another` value. However, no matter the value of the field, `another` is always set and I don't understand.

**Jquery**

```
  $('.test').click(function(e) {
  var counter = 0; 
  var fieldvalue = $("#fieldID").val();

  if (parseInt(fieldvalue >= 1)) {
    counter = fieldvalue;
  } else {
    counter = 0; // in reality this will be a dynamic value
  }
});
```

The problem is that `counter` always returns 0.

Comment: If you want `counter` to persist can't set it as  `var` for each click

Comment: @charlietfl, so I have to set it outside of the click? The value does need to change on every click.

Comment: Yes or you will reset it every time when you use `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean `fieldvalue` in `if (parseInt(fieldcounter >= 1)` and it has wrong parentheses.

```js
$('.test').click(function(e) {
  var counter = 0; // in reality this is a dynamic value
  var fieldvalue = $("#fieldID").val();

  if (parseInt(fieldvalue) >= 1) {
    counter = fieldvalue;
  }
  else {
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(counter)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fieldID">
<input type="button" value="fieldID" class="test">
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct variable seems to be `fieldvalue` and not `fieldcounter`. The >= comparison must be done outside the parseInt function. `counter` must also receive the result of the parseInt funcion, otherwise it could receive a String.

```
var fieldvalue = parseInt($("#fieldID").val());
if (fieldvalue >= 1) {
    counter = fieldvalue;
```

Comment: Sorry, that first bit was a mistake I made when preparing the code for SO. I'm going to test your other suggestion now.